# LoadRunner and the possibility to loadtest a database

Tags: database, loadrunner

What kind of support does LoadRunner have to loadtest a database. Is it possible to Connect directly to the jdbc "layer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it depends upon the database.

- LoadRunner supports connectivity with many native for SQL Server (Sybase and Microsoft variants), DB2, ORACLE and others.
- IT supports ODBC.
- Because of the JAva Virtual User type there is support for JDBC.
- Because of the VB virtual user type there is support for OleDB type connectivity.
- If you are looking at queues implemented in the database then you also have access to JMS via the web services virtual user or the Java Virtual User type.
- Within Visual Studio you have the capability of building a DLL style virtual user for C/C++ or VB which leverages your application source code
- Within Visual Studio and C# you can leverage the database connection options here for OleDB

For some types the interface can be recorded, for others it is hand coded or leveraging your source code.    It might help to better understand the nature of the client you are trying to reproduce, what programmatic interfaces are leveraged by the client and what is the next upstream component in terms of vendor and version.

Comment: I Guess goint through the GUI of the applicaton that is using the database is also an easy solution to this. And then monitoring the databse when loadtesting through GUI?

Comment: Why go through the GUI if you can just reproduce the queries?   You will wind up with a huge load generator infrastructure.   Just capture the calls and then use an API level virtual user.   Depending upon the database solution you may have multiple paths.   Yes, then monitor all of the classical database pinch points as well as pull the profile report at the end, but then this is good database monitoring advice for any performance test where a database is involved.